# Click on image and bring ViewPager

Tags: android

I have image carousel made with `picasso` which shows images in full screen. Now I need some image which takes 30% of screen and when I click on image it should bring my image carousel.

[image]

activity_main:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change Layout size onClick.

> ViewPager inside LinearLayout

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 100;
params.width = 100;
layout.setLayoutParams(params);
```

> AndroidImageSlider Library can be used to achieve slider.
>   [AndroidImageSlider](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider)

[image: OR]

> You must update to Viewpager2; an updated version on Viewpager.
>   [Read here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2)